# Configuring Azure PostgreSQL in Gitlab EE

Tags: gitlab, sidekiq, gitlab-omnibus, azure-postgresql, gitlab-ee

I am searching for some help in how to configure Azure PostgreSQL DB in a Docker Swarm based Gitlab instance.

Initially, I followed the documentation in https://docs.gitlab.com/13.6/ee/administration/postgresql/external.html. Yet I came to find out that the default provided user is in the form of *username*, whereas Azure requires it to be in the form of *username@hostname*. I tried passing the username in the gitlab.rb file (`gitlab_rails['db_username'] = 'username@hostname'`) but it still failed, even after replacing the @ with the %40 as URI encoded.

After some extensive searching, I found this documentation - https://docs.gitlab.com/13.6/ee/administration/environment_variables.html, which suggests using the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable to set the full connection string in the form `postgresql://username:password@hostname:port/dbname`, which I did and it did solve the issue for Gitlab itself communicating with Azure PostgreSQL (in this case I replaced the username with username%40hostname, according to Azure requirements).

Allas, the success was short lived since then I came to find out that neither Puma and Sidekiq can connect to the database, always throwing the following error:

```
==> /var/log/gitlab/sidekiq/current <==
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

After some searching, I found that `gitlab-ctl` is generating the following file when starting the Gitlab instance:

```
# This file is managed by gitlab-ctl. Manual changes will be
# erased! To change the contents below, edit /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
# and run `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`.
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  collation:
  database: <database>
  username: "<username>"
  password:
  host: "/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql"
  port: 5432
  socket:
  sslmode:
  sslcompression: 0
  sslrootcert:
  sslca:
  load_balancing: {"hosts":[]}
  prepared_statements: false
  statement_limit: 1000
  connect_timeout:
  variables:
    statement_timeout:
```

(database and username where removed)

Pretty much it ignores the `DATABASE_URL` env variable and assumes the now non-existing configuration parameters in gitlab.rb.

So, right now, I'm a bit out of options and was wondering if anyone has had a similar issue and, if so, how where you able to overcome this.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

TL/DR: Pass the `username@hostname` string directly into the gitlab_rails['db_username'] in double quotes. The documentation for connecting to an Azure PostgreSQL in the official Gitlab page is not correct.

So, after some searching and going deep into the Gitlab configuration, I came to find out that the issue is very specific and related with the usage of docker secrets.

In my gitlab.rb configuration file, in the database configuration part, I'm using the following:

```
### GitLab database settings
###! Docs: https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/database.html
###! **Only needed if you use an external database.**
gitlab_rails['db_adapter'] = "postgresql"
gitlab_rails['db_encoding'] = "unicode"
gitlab_rails['db_database'] = File.read('/run/secrets/postgresql_database')
gitlab_rails['db_username'] = File.read('/run/secrets/postgresql_user')
gitlab_rails['db_password'] = File.read('/run/secrets/postgresql_password')
gitlab_rails['db_host'] = File.read('/run/secrets/postgresql_host')
gitlab_rails['db_port'] = File.read('/run/secrets/postgresql_port')
gitlab_rails['db_sslmode'] = 'require'
```

Now, this exact configuration was used previously for testing purposes and worked (but without the usage of Azure PostgreSQL database). And I'm passing the correct secrets to docker and I've confirmed that the secrets in fact, do exist.

(Sidenote: Also, I've established that Gitlab uses the method  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection from the Ruby ActiveRecord::Base library in order to connect to the database)

Yet, when using the username@hostname configuration for the user and passing that into the postgresql_user secret, suddenly the ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection method assumes that the `@hostname` is the actual hostname to where I want to connect to. And I've confirmed that the secret is being generated correctly inside the docker container

Now, it gets even stranger because if I pass the username@hostname string directly to the gitlab.rb file  - gitlab_rails['db_username'] parameter - in double quotes, it suddenly starts connecting without complaining.

So, in short, if using an Azure PostgreSQL database for a dockerized Gitlab instance and using secrets to pass the configuration to the gitlab.rb file, ***don't*** pass the `username@hostame` through a secret, but put it directly in the gitlab.rb file.

I don't know if this is a specific issue of Ruby or of Gitlab (I'm not a Ruby developer), but I did try converting the File.read output to a String, to a symbol, used the File.open('filepath', &:readline) and other shenanigans, but nothing worked. So, if anyone out there would care to add their reason for this, please feel free to do so.

Also, the tutorial provided by Azure - https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-pt/azure/postgresql/connect-ruby - doesn't work with Gitlab, since it complains about the %40.

Hope this can help anyone out there.